# How can I specify where an image is uploaded

Tags: blocks, media

I have a slideshow block that does a slideshow for a news stories that take two images.  An image for the page and a teaser image for the slideshow.  but the image never shows up in the slideshow.  The image url is sites/default/files/styles/mt_slideshow/public   but the actual location of the image after its uploaded is sites/default/files.   so is there a way to force the image to be uploded where this site is looking, or change where the site looks to where the image  is uploaded?

Comment: It sounds like your image style files might not be generating. The original file is in /sites/default/files but your slideshow is using an image style 'mt_slideshow' which is generated by Drupal and placed in 'sites/default/files/styles/mt_slideshow/public' -- check your error log to see if there's anything related to this (/admin/reports/dblog). It could be a permissions issue or something else. You might also make sure that image style exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your site log in as adminstrator and go to

```
'/admin/config/media/file-system'
```

and you can find the place where you can define your path to save any uploaded files.

for Example your siteis example.com you have to access

"`**example.com//admin/config/media/file-system**`"  as Drupal Administrator and you can change the path there.

[image URLs messing up](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26311/image-urls-messing-up?rq=1)

possibly this will give you a answer

Comment: i did that.  i have set it to save files in sites/default files  but the url is still example.com/sites/default/files/styles/mt_slideshow/public/Penguins_1.jpg?itok=xALPiy4m

Comment: are you using image field for the images? if yes go to that field setting in your content type and check "File directory " if there is any directory name called "styles/mt_slideshow/public" in that field remove that and check

Comment: Yes its an image field.  the file directory box is blank.  i havent put anything in there

Comment: check this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26311/image-urls-messing-up?rq=1  i believe it helps

Comment: If I am reading that correctly it says this is a permission issue?  if i just chmod 777 to all of the directories in the file path it should fix my problem?

Comment: hopefully you are right :)

Comment: That didnt work for me but i did find a fix.  in the view, instead of using the original image there is an option for to set the kind of picture you want.  by changing it to a different option other than the original image it will create a new picture that can be found by drupal